# Segmentation Fault on returning integer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The following is my struct:

```
struct LR_State{
    int myState;
    int operation;  //-1 initial.  0 if shift, 1 if reduce.
    vector<string> symbols;
    vector<int> indeces;

    LR_State(int myState){
        operation = -1;
        this->myState = myState;
    }

    void addTransition(int op, int index, string symbol){
        if (operation==-1){
            operation = op;
        }
        symbols.push_back(symbol);
        indeces.push_back(index);
    }

    int getIndexOfSymbol(string symbol){
        int index = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<symbols.size(); i++){
            if (symbols.at(i).compare(symbol)==0){
                index = indeces.at(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

};
```

The issue I'm having is with the getIndexOfSymbol function.  It takes a string, matches it to an element in the symbols vector, and then returns the corresponding index in the indeces vector.

The following is a snippet of my code, and is where the function is actually called.  "states" is a vector of LR_States.  The function call of getIndexSymbol does not have any issues in the shift section, but occurs in the reduce section.  I've tried calling the exact function that causes the segfault literally outside of the if statement and it is does not cause a segfault.  Only inside of the "else if..." does it segfault.

```
        cout << states.at(currState).getIndexOfSymbol(symbol) << endl;  //no segfault

        if (states[currState].operation==0){
            //shift
            int newState = states.at(currState).getIndexOfSymbol(symbol);  //no segfault
            stateStack.push_back(newState);
            symbolStack.push_back(symbol);
            iss >> symbol;

        }
        else if (states[currState].operation==1){

            //reduce
            int rule = states.at(currState).getIndexOfSymbol(symbol);  //segfault here!
            for (int i=0; i<rules[rule-1].size()-1; i++){
                stateStack.pop_back();
                symbolStack.pop_back();
            }
            symbolStack.push_back(rules[rule-1][0]);
            //get the new state
            int newState = states.at(currState).getIndexOfSymbol(rules[rule-1][0]);
            stateStack.push_back(newState);
            symbolStack.push_back(rules[rule-1][0]);

            for (int i=0; i<rules[rule-1].size(); i++)
                cout << rules[rule-1][i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
```

I'm completely stumped by this inconsistent segfault behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code under the debugger to see exactly where it segfaults? The code also has some definite C++ antipatterns in it that might or might not contribute to the problem.

Comment: Can you show a complete program that produces the segfault? BTW, if you do not have a `catch` handler for the exceptions thrown by `at`, then throwing such an exception may appear as a segfault.

Comment: Here's a link to the full code.  Just a warning, the expiration has been set to 1 hour.  http://pastebin.com/Cs1Aytwc

Comment: And sample input:  http://pastebin.com/DQw3DEMF

Comment: This `for (int i=0; i<rules[rule-1].size()-1; i++)` is really fishy

Comment: rules is a vector<vector<string> >.  But the segfault actually occurs while returning in getIndexOfSymbol, so that line is not even reached.

Comment: Sounds like a corruption in the stack if you have a problem with the return of a function.

Comment: A note: Avoid states[currState] and use states.at(currState) when you are unsure if an index is valid (I usually avoid 'at' using a valid index)

Comment: Breakthrough:  Turns out that an immediate cout after the line would not print, but cerr would print fine.  So it does indeed pass the function call, and I will now be looking into the fishy line you've been warning me about.  Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest you replace your `vector<string> symbols; vector<int> indeces;` with a `map<string, int>`? According to that snippet, that's pretty much the intent and it will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll make things neater once my code is in working order.

Comment: A segfault in code like this is a near-guarantee to be exceeding array boundaries or driving through an unchecked `operator[i]` as opposed to `.at(i)` I would send this *immediately* through Valgrind, and I can all-but-guarantee you it will tell you where the problems(s) are in short order. (and stop using VLAs in C++, its a gnu-extension (likely) thing and isn't portable; just use `std::vector<>` instead). A past bin of your input would also be helpful. Sry I didn't get the one you linked before it expired.